# HCL Domino console error: [0D90:0061-1B28] [C&S]> ERROR | Release 12.0.2FP2 | csinit.cpp(980) : Invalid or nonexistent parent document (0x3C8)

Tags: lotus-domino

I am seeing so many lines in Domino console as the following:

```
[0D90:004E-21A4] 15/02/2024 09:14:58   [C&S Error]   50ACB4D45050FB6FC1258ABA004FA322   Release 12.0.2FP2   csinvoke.cpp (CCSEventDesc::InvokeInit) : (0x3C8): Invalid or nonexistent parent document
[0D90:004E-21A4] 15/02/2024 09:14:58   [C&S Error]   FC3B218952418073C1258ABA004F9D0A   Release 12.0.2FP2   csinvoke.cpp (CCSEventDesc::InvokeInit) : (0x3C8): Invalid or nonexistent parent document
[0D90:004E-21A4] 15/02/2024 09:14:58   [C&S Error]   F49338E22596A223C1258AB700358766   Release 12.0.2FP2   csinvoke.cpp (CCSEventDesc::InvokeInit) : (0x3C8): Invalid or nonexistent parent document
[0D90:004E-21A4] 15/02/2024 09:14:58,98 [C&S]> ERROR | Release 12.0.2FP2 | csinit.cpp(1623) : Invalid or nonexistent parent document (0x3C8)
[0D90:004E-21A4] 15/02/2024 09:14:58,98 [C&S]> ERROR | Release 12.0.2FP2 | csinit.cpp(980) : Invalid or nonexistent parent document (0x3C8)
[0D90:004E-21A4] 15/02/2024 09:14:58,98 [C&S]> ERROR | Release 12.0.2FP2 | csinit.cpp(417) : Invalid or nonexistent parent document (0x3C8)
[0D90:004E-21A4] 15/02/2024 09:14:58,98 [C&S]> ERROR | Release 12.0.2FP2 | csinit.cpp(477) : Invalid or nonexistent parent document (0x3C8)
[0D90:004E-21A4] 15/02/2024 09:14:58,98 [C&S]> ERROR | Release 12.0.2FP2 | csinvoke.cpp(CCSEventDesc::InvokeInit) : Invalid or nonexistent parent document (0x3C8)
[0D90:004E-21A4] 15/02/2024 09:14:59   [C&S Error]   5A54191E362DE7FBC1258AB700351DC9   Release 12.0.2FP2   csinvoke.cpp (CCSEventDesc::InvokeInit) : (0x3C8): Invalid or nonexistent parent document
```

On this server is running the following:
Replica,Router,Update,AMgr,Adminp,Sched,CalConn,RnRMgr,TRAVELER, ca, ldap, certmgr, collect, nomad

I can't find anything about it, and even ChatGPT is very generic about it :-)

Comment: Does this help? https://support.hcltechsw.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=5ededbe3db92291855f38d6d1396194d

Comment: Not so much. The problem is that the error repeat itself ever 10 minutes, for 5 specific UNID, without reference to a sender or receiver. These log are so many that the console.log reach very fast 10mb size. I am thinking about to write a little LS Class to scavenge the MTDATA and search UNID to find sender and receiver.

Comment: Can you just look for the documents via unid and see what the contents are. You might not even need them?

Answer (score 2):

These are typically calendar messages (C&S) that either come from sched, calconn or rnrmgr. Unfortunately the UNID does not give you a hint about the database where this error occurs.

It is possible, that this has something to do with responses to invitations as well, then you would find a message in routing logs and maybe find the reason for this messages.

If you cannot identify the database from "surrounding" logs you could either try "tell sched validate USERNAME" for several users and find out if any of these can be associated with the message.

If this is not successful then you could try to "brute force find" the documents by creating an agent that searches through all mailfiles for the UNIDs.

That would be like:

- Use NotesDBDirectory to run through all databases on server
- check db.FilePath to determin if the database is in the "mail" path
- open the db (as they are not opened when retrieved from NotesDBDirectory)
- get the document from db with GetDocumentByUNID() from database (wrap in error handler, as this will throw an error if the document is not found)
- write out the database when you found the document